# What is this creepy little thing that I found sticking on my bathroom wall?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: dark brownish chrysalis-like structure surrounded by a network of dark hairs]
I found this creepy looking thing hanging on my bathroom wall. This is actually the 2nd time I have seen it. The first one I saw looked kind of dried up already stuck in between the walls. But this looks fresh and new. It's scary and gives me goosebumps just looking at it. Can somebody pls help

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — photos must be uploaded; 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) an estimate of the size of the organism; and 4) the species-identification tag. I fixed 1 & 4 already, but please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 3):

This is the pupal stage of a *lepidopteran* (i.e. a butterfly/moth). The pupa is encased in the brown silken cocoon in the centre of the 'net'. The 'net' itself is built from the *setae* (hairs) of the caterpillar, which it sheds prior to cocoon formation.

Here's some photos of similar formations:

1. http://www.richard-seaman.com/Insects/Vietnam/Highlights/index.html#Chrysalis
2. https://www.nhm.ac.uk/wpy/gallery/2019-the-hairnet-cocoon?tags=ed.current
3. https://besgroup.org/2015/11/05/a-parasitic-fly-emerged-from-the-cocoon-of-a-footman-moth/